# Open tab in next window with javascript document.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, events

i am using this script to open a file on click having id link,I can figure out the way to open the file in next tab on click,Thanks in advance

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
 location = document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("href");
}, false );
</script>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: now this script is opening the file in same page,i want to open the file in next tab

Comment: you should include an example of your DOM, what the user might click on

Comment: @denov he is not clicking

Comment: @mplungjan in the questions it says 'on click'

Comment: But the code does not

Answer (score 1):

```
location = ....
window.open(location);
```

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for `window.open()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will open your url in a new tab:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("href");
    window.open( location , '_blank' );
}, false );
```

Comment: i'm going to guess that 'wpcf7mailsent' isn't a event the author of the question is using based on the question itselft.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an eventListener on the node you want to call a function to open the new window/tab.

Your questions didn't have details on what your DOM looked like so here's an example using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
<div>
  <button id="file1" data-url="https://www.google.com">file 1</button>
  <button id="file2" data-url="https://www.slashdot.org">file 2</button>
</div>

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', openNewTab, false);
}

function openNewTab(event) {
   window.open(event.target.dataset.url, '_blank');
}
```

A fully working example - https://jsfiddle.net/denov/kza19gbf/1/

I'd suggest you take a look at the following docs

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset